# vue-i18n how to abbreviate currency display?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-i18n

Is there a way to achieve what d3 can do with [precisionPrefix](https://github.com/d3/d3-format#precisionPrefix) in the vue-i18n ecosystem?

There is an open issue [here](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/369).

And I found an old issue for `Intl` object [here](https://github.com/tc39/ecma402/issues/37).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One **hacky** way will be replace `VueI18n.n` with your own handler.

1. add custom property=abbreviate to `VueI18n.numberFormats` in order to determinate if apply special style.
2. save origial `VueI18n.n` to `VueI18n.n1` (we will still use `VueI18n.n1` for other styles)
3. uses your own handler to replace `VueI18n.n`, then inside the handler, check if `numberFormatter.abbreviate` is true, **if yes**, apply your special style (At below demo, simply uses regex expression to implement it).

**Like below simple demo:**

**PS:** below I uses one **simple** regex expression to apply the styles, for some special number format, it may not work, you need to improve it by yourself.

```js
Vue.use(VueI18n)

const numberFormats = {
   'en-US': {
     currency: {
       style: 'currency', currency: 'USD', currencyDisplay: 'symbol', useGrouping: false
     }
   },
   'ja-JP': {
     currency: {
       style: 'currency', currency: 'JPY', currencyDisplay: 'name', 
abbreviate: true, // custom property to determinate whether apply special styles
       maximumSignificantDigits: 4, useGrouping: true
     }
   }
 }

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  numberFormats
})

i18n.n1 = i18n.n // save default i18n.n to i18n.n1

i18n.n= function (nValue, nStyle) {
  let numberFormatter = this.getNumberFormat(this.locale) // get NumberFormat Based on locale
  if (numberFormatter[nStyle].abbreviate) { // if custom property is true
    let newValue = Math.round(nValue/1000000) // divide 10^6 for millions, divide 10^3 for K .etc
    return this.n1(newValue, nStyle).replace(/(\d[\d|,]*)(\.\d+)?/, '$1 $2M')
  }
  return this.n1(nValue, nStyle) // for others , use default i18n.n to process.
}

Vue.config.productionTip = false

app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  i18n,
  data: {
    test: 1234567890,
    language: 'en-US'
  },
  computed: {
    computedTest: function () {
      return this.$n(this.test, 'currency')
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleLanguage: function () {
      this.language = this.language === 'en-US' ? 'ja-JP' : 'en-US'
      this.$i18n.locale = this.language
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-i18n/7.8.0/vue-i18n.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="toggleLanguage()">Language </button>
  <p>Language: [{{language}}]</p>
  <p>Org: {{test}}</p>
  <p>localed: {{computedTest}}</p>
</div>
```

**Edit:** another approach: uses [D3-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-format)

```js
Vue.use(VueI18n)

const numberFormats = {
   'en-US': {
     currency: {
       style: 'currency', currency: 'USD', currencyDisplay: 'symbol', useGrouping: false
     }
   },
   'ja-JP': {
     currency: {
       style: 'currency', currency: 'JPY', currencyDisplay: 'name', 
abbreviate: true, // custom property to determinate whether apply special styles
       maximumSignificantDigits: 4, useGrouping: true
     }
   }
 }

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  numberFormats
})

let d3Locales = {}

axios.get('https://unpkg.com/d3-format@1/locale/ja-JP.json')
.then(function (response) {
  d3Locales['ja-JP'] = response.data
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});

axios.get('https://unpkg.com/d3-format@1/locale/en-US.json')
.then(function (response) {
  d3Locales['en-US'] = response.data
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});

i18n.n1 = i18n.n // save default i18n.n to i18n.n1

i18n.n= function (nValue, nStyle) {
  let numberFormatter = this.getNumberFormat(this.locale) // get NumberFormat Based on locale
  if (numberFormatter[nStyle].abbreviate) { // if custom property is true
    d3.formatDefaultLocale(d3Locales[this.locale])
    let p = d3.precisionPrefix(1e4, 1e6),
        f = d3.formatPrefix("$." + p, 1e6)
    return f(nValue);
  }
  return this.n1(nValue, nStyle) // for others , use default i18n.n to process.
}

Vue.config.productionTip = false

app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  i18n,
  data: {
    test: 1234567890,
    language: 'en-US'
  },
  computed: {
    computedTest: function () {
      return this.$n(this.test, 'currency')
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleLanguage: function () {
      this.language = this.language === 'en-US' ? 'ja-JP' : 'en-US'
      this.$i18n.locale = this.language
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-i18n/7.8.0/vue-i18n.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-format.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="toggleLanguage()">Language </button>
  <p>Language: [{{language}}]</p>
  <p>Org: {{test}}</p>
  <p>localed: {{computedTest}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposal. What you silently say is there is no classic way to do it... I will couple your surcharge approach with d3-format. I have to translate my numbers into 7 languages, with lot of different numbers, I can't do it from scratch.

Comment: @GeorgeAbitbol because i18n uses [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat), but this API can't implement your requirements. Instead of Regex expression, another approach will be uses one thrid party lib to reach the goal, like [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/)

Comment: @GeorgeAbitbol, I didn't use D3 before, but after google, it seems this library may fit your demands better, [D3-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-format)

Comment: The answer from the author of i18n > https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/369#issuecomment-398097036

Answer (score 0):

After digging around for a while, I decided to write my own helper methods as the price displaying on my site is quite big so abbreviation is a must.  @Sphinx solution seems to be too much effort just for making the number shorter.

I created a utils file and import i18n into it.  The idea is from [how to convert numbers to million in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734201/how-to-convert-numbers-to-million-in-javascript)

```
//Utils.js
import { i18n } from 'boot/i18n.ts'

export const CURRENCY_CALCULATOR = (price) => {
  let abbreviatedPrice = price
  if (i18n.locale === 'en-us') {
    abbreviatedPrice = Math.abs(Number(price)) >= 1.0e+6
      ? Math.abs(Number(price)) / 1.0e+6 + "M"
      : Math.abs(Number(price)) >= 1.0e+3
      ? Math.abs(Number(price)) / 1.0e+3 + "K"
      : Math.abs(Number(price));
  } else {
    // Other languages uses different units
    abbreviatedPrice = Math.abs(Number(price)) >= 1.0e+4
      ? Math.abs(Number(price)) / 1.0e+4 + i18n.t('sorting.tenThousands')
      : Math.abs(Number(price));
  }
  // setup currency symbol by yourself, because I use the same symbol for both
  return `$ ${abbreviatedPrice}` 
}
```

In your component

```
<template>
  <div class="col-auto">
    {{ calculateCurrency(item.price) }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { CURRENCY_CALCULATOR } from '../constants/Utils'

export default {
  name: '<<component name here>>',
  props: ['<<your props here>>']
  methods: {
    calculateCurrency (price) {
      return CURRENCY_CALCULATOR(price)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```