# How to fetch data from api?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, fetch-api

I want to fetch data (particularly market cap)from api and display it inside my div. But my html diplays no data on execution. What could I be doing wrong?

```
<text id="result"></text>

  <script>
  // API for get requests 

  let fetchRes = fetch(
        "https://api.lunarcrush.com/v2?data=assets&key=n8dyddsipg5611qg6bst9&symbol=AVAX"); 

   // fetchRes is the promise to resolve 

   // it by using.then() method 

   fetchRes.then((res) => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result.config.data.0.market_cap;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
      
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Why not just chain the `.then()` directly to the `fetch()`?
2. You seem to have a bit of confusion on how to access the data in your structure - what you're after is `result.data[0].market_cap`.

```js
// API for get requests 

let fetchRes = fetch("https://api.lunarcrush.com/v2?data=assets&key=n8dyddsipg5611qg6bst9&symbol=AVAX")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result.data[0].market_cap;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

```html
<text id="result"></text>
```

Aside: you should probably invalidate your API key that you've included here, as it's now out in public and can be used to forge requests as you to this API.

Comment: Yes it worked thanks, one more question I want to display the number as 7.69Billion instead of 7692083188.is there any possible way it can be acheived?

Comment: @Prime That would be outside the scope of the question as you've asked it, but I would encourage you to use the search functionality for questions like this that have already been asked, as it would be a duplicate of [how to convert numbers to million in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734201/how-to-convert-numbers-to-million-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I am using **jQuery Framework** to do this easily.
Check the code below.

```sh
<script>
    $.get(
        "https://api.lunarcrush.com/v2",
        {
            data: "assets",
            key: "n8dyddsipg5611qg6bst9",
            symbol: "AVAX"
        },
        function (result){
            data = JSON.parse(result);
        }
    );
</script>
```

You can use **jQuery** by adding the following code in your `<head>` tag.

```sh
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why suggest adding an additional 31kb of overhead for a library that would only be used for a singular purpose, especially when support for the Fetch API is [pretty ubiquitous nowadays](https://caniuse.com/fetch)...?

Answer (score 1):

Use result.config.data[0].market_cap; instead of result.config.data.0.market_cap;

```
let fetchRes = fetch( 
"https://api.lunarcrush.com/v2?data=assets&key=n8dyddsipg5611qg6bst9&symbol=AVAX"); 

  

        // fetchRes is the promise to resolve

        // it by using.then() method

        fetchRes.then((res) => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result.config.data[0].market_cap;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it cleaner and simpler:

```js
const fetchData = async(url) => (await fetch(url)).json();

fetchData("https://api.lunarcrush.com/v2?data=assets&key=n8dyddsipg5611qg6bst9&symbol=AVAX")
  .then(res => {
    result.innerText = res.data[0].market_cap;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

```html
<text id="result"></text>
```